# django admin: How to customize one field in fieldsets?

Tags: django, admin, fieldset

I try to make one field in django admin's fieldsets to show only certain data, but according to [django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), only an example of `list_display` is shown to be able to customize. I tried the similar approach on `fieldsets` like the following:

In models.py:

```
def ports_with_same_scanner(self):
    return PortList.objects.filter(scanner=self.scanner)
ports_with_same_scanner.short_description = 'port_lists'
```

In admin.py, this won't work:

```
fieldsets = (
            ('Scan Template', { 
            'fields': ( ('name', 'scanner', 'ports_with_same_scanner',), 'comment', ('in_use',
                'fc_growing', 'nc_growing'), 'nvt_prefs')
            }),
)
```

However, if I do this:

```
list_display = ('name', 'scanner', 'ports_with_same_scanner', 'comment', 'in_use', 'fc_growing', 'nc_growing', 'nvt_prefs')
```

the `ports_with_same_scanner` works just fine. The problem is that I don't want to change my display from `fieldsets` to `list_display`, I wonder how can I achieve the same functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would it work to apply the filter at the model level? If so you can use the [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) attribute on the model's `ForeignKeyField`.

Alternatively you could override the [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) attribute of the modelAdmin class.

Something like -

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "ports_with_same_scanner":
            kwargs["queryset"] = PortList.objects.filter(scanner=self.scanner)
        return super(YourModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

(Apologies if I've misunderstood the question)

Comment: Since `ports_with_same_scanner` is not an actual field on the Model, how is the above code not erring out?  If I try to define a non-model-field in my `fieldsets` definition, Django will bork out with `FieldError: Unknown field(s) (my_field_1, my_field_2) specified for MyModel. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class MyModelAdmin.`, and it will bork out BEFORE it calls the `formfield_for_foreignkey()` method.  How do you define `ports_with_same_scanner` in a way that keeps Django happy?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if real problem at past ... I always using simple approach - to adding a name of method to the `readonly_fields = ()`

Example:

**`models.py`**

```
class My(models.Model):

    def custom_name(self):
        return 'test'
    custom_name.allow_tags = False
    custom_name.short_description = 'custom_name'
```

**`admin.py`**

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
            (None, {
                    'fields': ('custom_name', )
            }),
    )
    readonly_fields = ('custom_name', )
```

It must be working Django >=1.7 It seems the approach can be apply to early version of Django^ but I don't testing

Comment: works for me in django 1.9, but with custom_name.short_description = 'your_custom_name', with _('your_custom_name') dont work. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Sorry, it is my typo. Fixed